# how to set a load balancer for clustered MQTT brokers

Tags: spring, load-balancing, real-time, mqtt, messagebroker

I'm working on a project to develop a real time mobile messaging application that needs to have advanced message filtering based on message content and user's balance, meaning that if the user has ran out of balance or if he's sending content that violates the policy the messages have to be blocked.

For this reason I need to implement some load balancing solution that scans **published** messages and could also determine if the message should be blocked based on the rules above, hence I can't implement a basic proxy as I need special rules applied on each message.

**The difficult part:**
Mobile app needs to receive **subscription** messages (connection acknowledgement too) without passing through the load balancer preferably (see my next point).

The problem is that the only way I could forward subscription messages to the mobile app would be by handling connections and subscriptions in the load balancer which is disastrous. I need the connections to be transparent and the load balancer stateless.

How can I accomplish this? (if it's of any help my current design involves Java component with spring boot for load balancing and VerneMQ as the message broker)

Answer (score 1):

Try

Mobile App  -- > MQTT Broker -- > Message Scan / Block Algorithm  -- > MQTT Broker -- > Subscriber.

Your mobile app should have the intelligence to stop messages when the app runs out of balance after the first message.

So the MQTT Broker should not send the message to its subscriber directly at its layer. It should send out messsages that were received after processing.

Not sure anyone has a ready made solution for this flow. But doable.

Comment: you're right but in terms of security I thought it'd be good to have back end validation for numerous reasons.

Comment: I belive you will be able to add your security  (validation) layer as part of the Message Scan and Alogirthm Block.

Comment: I like the approach the only problem I have with it is the redundancy with the MQTT broker, more publishes would equal greater delivery time

Comment: Redundancy in broker can be by running multiple brokers in parallel and having a distributor inbetween for an internal load balancing. That will help run multiple brokers receive and send in parallel. You have to make sure your validation block is made without single point of failure.  The architecture is little harder to explain. This is sometihng we do as part of our [Bevywise IoT Platform](https://bevywise.com/iot-platform/)